# Label is not updated until the screen is touched

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I an using Xamarin.forms implementing an iOS APP, but found out sometimes label on the screen will not update.

I have tried:

1. device.invokeonmainthread
2. Bind my label with a string and then update the string

Both doesn't work.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), () =>
{
...
...

...
...
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Label.Text = xxx;
    });
    return true;
});
```

The xxx in the code is a dynamic value

1, 2, 3....

But the screen just show 1. And not changed.

But if I touched the screen. It update one time.

Is there any possible reason or what method can I try?

Or for a shorten solution. Can I write a function to disguise a touch?

This only happened on iOS.

In android system. No issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you call this code in your app?

Comment: Can you please show us a full example which can reproduce the issue? I use your code and the value updated well.